# adding new column to postgresql and access

Tags: postgresql, ms-access

I'm using access as a frontend to a postgresql db, I've inherited it.
I've added a new column to a table in postgresql, but I can't access it in access. Do I need to add the same column in access and define the link or would it do this automatically. Any help is welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using linked tables, to get the new column to show up I needed to refresh the linked connection.